# Iterate over object properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

In my aurelia app, I need to display a list of elements. For performance reasons, these elements are stored as a javascript object instead of an array. That is what the object looks like :

```
var x = {
    0 : {...},
    3 : {...},
    5 : {...},
}
```

Here is the part of the template where I display these elements :

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li repeat.for="property of object | ObjectToArray">
            ${ property.text }
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

As you can see, I'm currently using a value converter to be able to iterate over my object properties. The value converter simply converts the object to an array :

```
export class ObjectToArrayValueConverter {
    toView(data : {[key : string] : any}) : any[] {

        var array = [];

        for (var key in data) {
            array.push(data[key]);
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

This solution works very well as long as properties do not get removed or added to the object after the list has been rendered for the first time. The reason is that the value converter only gets called once.
In my case, however, I need my list to stay up to date whatever happens.

I know I could create a function that could be manually called every time the object is modified, but that would add some unwanted complexity in business logic.

Is there an aurelia functionality that coud help me achieve what I want ? I could not find any help in the docs. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys using `Object.prototype.keys` and call `Array.prototype.map` on it to get an array every time you want to list it out.

```
var obj={...}; //Object with many keys
var genArray = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){return obj[key];})


//Using as a function
function getKeysAsArray(obj){
    if(!obj){
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){return obj[key]});
}
```

Comment: Yeah,  that is what I meant with *a function that could be manually called every time the object is modified*. But your code is really concise so it might be useful any way :)

Comment: Updated answer with a function :)

Comment: You're a lamb !

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier strategy, as shown in the [docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/9):

```
export class KeysValueConverter {
  toView(obj) {
    return Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<p repeat.for="greeting of friends | keys">${greeting}, ${friends[greeting].name}!</p>
```

Comment: Is my list going to be up to date in case a property is added or removed ?